# Finding a specific line from a text file and displaying it in a TextBox

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently making a little dictionary application in VB.NET. I have a text file with the words in it and the definition next to it separated by a comma. I am struggling to find a way to display the definition in a `TextBox` after the user searches for the word.

This is the code I have used to parse the file into a `ListBox` to show all the words. I haven't done anything with the definition as I'm struggling to get this to work:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim line As String
For Each line In File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\My Project\Swift Word\Words.txt")
    Dim parts As String() = line.Split(New Char() {","c})
    Dim part As String
    For Each part In parts
        Console.WriteLine(1)
    Next
    i += 1
Next
```

Comment: You need to show us what you tried so far

Comment: Assuming you've parsed the string out of the file and assigned it to the MyDefinition variable, if the textbox is named Textbox1, you just need to do `Textbox1.text = MyDefinition`

Comment: Pretty unclear what you cannot make work as you haven't tried anything yet.  Use a Dictionary(Of String, String) to store the file content so you can quickly look up the definition (value) of the word (key).